# Rstudio: Troubleshooting dominance analysis script

Tags: r, statistics

I have been trying to get this dominance analysis running https://supp.apa.org/psycarticles/supplemental/apl0000361/Supplemental-Material.zip, but I keep getting this:

"Error in if (class(userDat) == "data.frame") { :
the condition has length > 1"

I have been able to get the script running by "hardcoding" all the "default values for the simulation", but then I am only able to run the uncorrected analysis.

I suspect something's wrong with the if-else statement, but I have not been able to solve it thus far. I have tried using both a data.frame object containing the real observations a correlation matrix from observed data.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

`class` can return a vector with more than one entry, such as:

```
> userDat = tibble::tibble()
> class(userDat)
[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
```

And then the condition inside `if()` will have length > 1:

```
> class(userDat) == "data.frame"
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Thus, you can modify your condition to:

```
> any(class(userDat) == "data.frame")
[1] TRUE
```

or

```
> "data.frame" %in% class(userDat)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Hi! That worked! But only if I run the script without the spurious predictor. When I run with spurIV = T, I get the following error:

 Error in names(diffZero) <- iv.names : 
  'names' attribute [6] must be the same length as the vector [0]

Can you help me figure that one out too? Thank you for taking the time to help me!

Comment: You're welcome! Well, i can't acess the link you posted, so I don't have the context to find out. In that sense, you should learn a bit more about how to ask good questions on SO. Check //stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example